# Spring Ioc Beans management

Tags: spring, spring-ioc

I have a question about spring IoC management. I created Bean in:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {....}

    @Bean
    public XmlMapper xmlMapper() {
        return new XmlMapper();
    }
}
```

These beans work fine as expected. But Default ObjectMapper get overridden and
  @RestController try to parse the request and expect that payload is XML.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XmlMapper` is a sub class of `ObjectMapper` so if you declare one bean of this type, Spring will use that one and inject it where needed.

If you want to still use basic `ObjectMapper` elsewhere. You can declare another bean ObjectMapper. You may have to indicate it as primary.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {....}

    @Bean
    public XmlMapper xmlMapper() {
        return new XmlMapper();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary //Not sure if needed
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```